# AIX - redirect hostname in other subnet via route

Tags: routing, aix, metric

I have two servers: one application and one database. They are both connected over two interfaces. One is frontend LAN with 100 Mbit and one is in the backbone LAN with 1 Gbit.

Well, planned is that only the users who are connecting to the application server go over the frontend LAN to the application sever and the admins who are connecting to the DB via command line go over the frontend LAN to the DB server.

But I want the two servers to explicitly talk to each other via the backbone LAN. Well I could just deactivate the adapter in the frontend LAN between these two Servers or I could change the /etc/hosts and put the frontend-hostname from the other server to the backend-ip. But I find that ugly.

Is there a possibility to tell e. g. the application server that when everytime he tired to connect to the frontend Hostname/IP he should instead connect to the backend IP? Like configuring a route via smitty?

Answer (score 1):

Just add line in /etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.10  app
192.168.1.11  db
192.168.100.10 app-bb
192.168.100.11 db-bb
```

where

- app, bd and bb stand for application, database ans backbone,
- 192.168.1.X are IPs for frontend lan,
- 192.168.100.X are IPs for backbone lan.

nos in all your configuration backups and like, just use `-bb` ending name, for instance nfs mount are done using

```
mount app-bb:/data /data/remote
```

this will ensure all traffic goes through hish speed lan.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that was the ugly solution i didnt want to do, because it involves changing the configuration of every app which is communicating between these two hosts.

I have come up with a better solution. I set up a static route between the servers. So when Server b has the two hostnames
192.168.1.11 db
and
192.168.100.11 db-bb

When on Server A, I did
OS>smitty tcpip -> Further configuration -> Static Routes -> Add a static Route
then i added a static route of type host. I routed source hostname db to target host name db-bb. Works like a charm without reconfiguring anything in applications or mounts.